# Making a "scrolling" menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I want to make a scrolling menu with my menu on my free hosted site.

What I mean by a scrolling menu is like at the bottom of the screen @ CNET.com & ThePheed.net,  my site is currently at Trigoblocks.comuf.com.

Does anybody know how to do this and could teach me or lead me in the right direction? (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You div css should be something like the follwing:

```
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
left:0px;
width:100%;
```

As far as the wrap around effect in cnet is concerned, its probably a transparent .png positioned at the top of the div.

**Example**

```
<div style="height:200%;">Make scroll bar appear</div>
<div style="position:fixed; bottom:0; left:0px; height:25px; width:100%; background-color:#3c3c3c; border:solid 1px gray; padding:2px;">
  <div style="color:gray;">Stuff</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Heh, and I thought you wanted something like this: http://jsbin.com/irovo/2

Guess I should visit cnet some day..

Comment: Ah. JSbin looks cool, too. I'll probably use it sometime. Thanks! (:

Comment: Sure thing, I just found it today myself, it is pretty handy.